# How to align hight of flexbox children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a holy grail flexbox layout with a lot of text in the middle area. When resizing the window (try decreasing the height), the height of the columns on the sides does not align with the article or everything gets cut off. I've tried playing with min- and max-height and flexbox attributes like align-items, but it seems like I'm failing to understand something fundamental.

```
Please help me understand.
```

**Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nazurii/sz01gn3k/1/).**

Edit: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzbd0.png) of decreasing window size and scrolling down, so the content is cut and the site is filled with white space

Comment: you need to provide a fix height to your nav section currently you have written `height: 10vh` change it to `height: 85px`. Because  `vh` changes according to window height

Comment: @Abhi The nav section is fine and acts as it's supposed to. The problem lays in the main div and its children. If you decrease the window height, the content gets cut off and the site is filled with white space. [Like so](https://i.imgur.com/onO6cEi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of styles that set height, but you actually don't need them. Try to remove all of them and adjust a few things.

In order for `.mains` to fill the full height you need three things:

1. Set body to `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;`.
2. Set body to `height: 100vh;`.
3. Set `.mains` to `flex: 1`. It will make it fill the entire space.

This should be enough. Please see a sample:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
}

footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.mains {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 20%;
}

.left {
  background-color: orange;
}

.right {
  background-color: grey;
}

article {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <span>Home</span>
    <span>News</span>
    <span>Contact</span>
    <span>About</span>
  </nav
    >
  <div class="mains">
    <aside class="left">
      <p>left</p>
      <p>left</p>
      <p>left</p>
    </aside>
    <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nemo odit mollitia aliquam deserunt vel fuga ratione veritatis praesentium nam ipsam magnam tenetur illo, ipsa nobis totam. Aperiam, eligendi blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ratione voluptas magni eaque dicta recusandae voluptate perferendis, quas quod excepturi mollitia tenetur in dolorum. Qui, magnam molestias! Exercitationem, vero id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, earum? Doloremque, hic. Nisi vitae ad vel odio ut et, quia sed repudiandae quas ipsa cupiditate! Voluptas fugit quis animi assumenda! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nemo odit mollitia aliquam deserunt vel fuga ratione veritatis praesentium nam ipsam magnam tenetur illo, ipsa nobis totam. Aperiam, eligendi blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ratione voluptas magni eaque dicta recusandae voluptate perferendis, quas quod excepturi mollitia tenetur in dolorum. Qui, magnam molestias! Exercitationem, vero id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, earum? Doloremque, hic. Nisi vitae ad vel odio ut et, quia sed repudiandae quas ipsa cupiditate! Voluptas fugit quis animi assumenda! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nemo odit mollitia aliquam deserunt vel fuga ratione veritatis praesentium nam ipsam magnam tenetur illo, ipsa nobis totam. Aperiam, eligendi blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ratione voluptas magni eaque dicta recusandae voluptate perferendis, quas quod excepturi mollitia tenetur in dolorum. Qui, magnam molestias! Exercitationem, vero id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, earum? Doloremque, hic. Nisi vitae ad vel odio ut et, quia sed repudiandae quas ipsa cupiditate! Voluptas fugit quis animi assumenda! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est nemo odit mollitia aliquam deserunt vel fuga ratione veritatis praesentium nam ipsam magnam tenetur illo, ipsa nobis totam. Aperiam, eligendi blanditiis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ratione voluptas magni eaque dicta recusandae voluptate perferendis, quas quod excepturi mollitia tenetur in dolorum. Qui, magnam molestias! Exercitationem, vero id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, earum? Doloremque, hic. Nisi vitae ad vel odio ut et, quia sed repudiandae quas ipsa cupiditate! Voluptas fugit quis animi assumenda!</article>
    <aside class="right">
      <p>right</p>
    </aside>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <a href="">Sitemap</a>
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">News</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still results in white space below the footer and the article text is cut off

Comment: I adjusted the answer